# Почему падает плазмоид при изменении времени таймера?

Tags: python, linux, kde

Написал себе плазмоид, который тупо дёргает одну xml из инета и строит по ней график, питон я совершенно не знаю, и собирал из частей по всему инету. Потом решил добавить таймер, для обновления инфы, применил вот такую вещь

```
self.update_event = threading.Timer(10.0,self.lookUp).start()
```

где lookUp это метод который отправляет запрос
в обработчике ответа от сервера, но при старте плазмоид падает, причём работает он только если записать

```
self.update_event = threading.Timer(10,self.lookUp).start()
```

тоесть его устраивает только цифра 10, и именно в таком формате записи, без точки, при изменении занчения на большее или меньшее скрипт падает с таким сообщением в консоли

```
KCrash: Application 'plasmoidviewer' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib64/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
KCrash: Connect sock_file=/home/deadik/.kde4/socket-gentoo/kdeinit4__0
plasmoidviewer: Fatal IO error: client killed
```

Comment: `Timer()` обязан принимать не целые числа. `python -c "import threading; threading.Timer(10.0, lambda: None).start()"` работает как есть. Кстати `.start()` всегда возвращает `None` -- бессмысленно сохранять это значение.

Comment: Меня больше волнует не формат записи, а то что сейчас работает с 10.0, а вот с 11.0, 5.0,198.0,любое_число.0, 42 не рабоатет, падает сразу.

Comment: Это не про формат записи. Команда из моего комментария (выполни её в bash или cmd.exe, итд) демонстрирует что `Timer()` работает с `10.0`. Я не сомневаюсь, что она также будет работать с 5.0, 198.0, итд.

Comment: Не сомневаюсь что в консоли работает. Если перечитать вопрос внимательно, то там описывается проблема, и сказано, что проблема возникает при использовании в плазмоиде.

Comment: если `threading` не является одноимённым модулем из стандартной библиотеки Питона или используется как-либо изменённая версия, то это нужно явно указать в вопросе. Для **стандартного** threading, указанный мой код будет работать где бы он не исполнялся (консоль просто самый простой способ проверить). Чтобы более понятным сделать вопрос, хорошо бы увидеть [минимальный *самодостаточный* пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Под изменённой версией я **не** имею ввиду версию *threading*, которую **Вы** написали, а (к примеру) threading пропатченый для gevent -- и даже в этом случае интерфейс тот же и поэтому `Timer()` должен целые числа принимать, если бага нет. Если используется стандартный `threading`, то **не важно** какой код его вызывает: `threading.Timer` обязан принимать `10.0`. Моя гипотеза: ошибка не связана с `10.0` vs. `10`.

Comment: Посмотрите в мой сетевой профиль -- мне не нужно "гуглить", чтобы аргументы для `Timer()` узнать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения проблемы я не нашёл, тут два варианта, либо проблема восспроизводится при определённом стечении условий, либо при разработке плазмоидов это класс не использвется. Поставленную задачу решил через QTimer